# Hosting asp.net MVC 5 website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-7, iis-express

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3u4kJ.jpg)
I am having troubles with iis. I have created a website and published my files in here - the structure looks good. Now when I try to load that site from outside - I get the server error as if something is broken here or not set properly.

I've tested the same functionality locally  and I can host just fine. Anyone know what might be missing here?

Comment: You might be missing quite a few things.  Is ASP.NET installed on the server you are testing on? Are the ISAPI filters registered. Did you configure a site in IIS or just put the files in wwwroot? How did you publish your application?

Comment: hi , i don't know about "ISAPI" filters....first i publish my web appliacation in folder in  (D:) , then i start with IIS management , add web , same path of publish ....it works with localhost , but with ip , dose not , please help

Comment: what's Your error message ?

Comment: You need to be more specific with some of the details, How was IIS installed on the server, What .NET framework did you create the application in. Did you use the Microsoft Web Platform Installer to install options on your server. Did you publish your application from visual studio direct to the server, what files did you tell visual studio to add to the published site. there are many variables here that we would need to know to help you succesfully.

Comment: okey i resolve the problem , there was a missing file :D ....BUT NOW how to connect to data base , Impossible d'ouvrir la base de données "my data base" demandée par la connexion. La connexion a échoué.
Échec de l'ouverture de session de l'utilisateur 'IIS APPPOOL\seif